# How to unfreeze window in Tkinter when executing commands in SSH

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i have a python3 program that creates a GUI, asking for username, password, and ip addresses.

when i click connect the window freezes when executing the function.

Is there a way to unfreeze this window?.

i have this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("")

        # Create labels
        self.ip_label = tk.Label(master, text="IP Addresses:")
        self.user_label = tk.Label(master, text="Username:")
        self.password_label = tk.Label(master, text="Password:")

        # Create textboxes
        self.ip_textbox = tk.Text(master, width=39, height=10)
        self.user_textbox = tk.Entry(master, width=30)
        self.password_textbox = tk.Entry(master, width=30, show="*")

        # Create output window
        self.output_window = tk.Text(master, width=60, height=20)

        # Create connect button
        self.connect_button = tk.Button(master, text="Connect", command=self.connect)

        # Place labels on the left and textboxes on the right
        self.user_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)
        self.user_textbox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E)

        self.password_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)
        self.password_textbox.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E)

        self.ip_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)
        self.ip_textbox.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E)

        self.output_window.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)

        self.connect_button.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E)

    def connect(self):
        ips = self.ip_textbox.get("1.0", tk.END).splitlines()
        username = self.user_textbox.get()
        password = self.password_textbox.get()

        for ip in ips:
            device = {
                'device_type': 'cisco_xr',
                'ip': ip.strip(),
                'username': username,
                'password': password,
                'secret': password
            }
            try:
                with ConnectHandler(**device) as ssh:
                    self.output_window.insert(tk.END, f"Connected to {ip}\n")
                    output = ssh.send_command("show ver")
                    self.output_window.insert(tk.END, output + "\n")
            except Exception as e:
                self.output_window.insert(tk.END, f"Error connecting to {ip}: {e}\n")

# Create GUI
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance

i would like to not freeze the window while executing all the program

Comment: You can use [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) to execute the task in a thread.

Comment: Yes, threading was the answer thanks a lot